# Graph API equivalent for sharing photo?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Trying to create a wall post with photo attached. Photo is a Facebook-hosted photo within some album.

Problem here - Facebook won't allow including facebook-hosted content in posts ((#100) FBCDN image is not allowed in stream )

From the Web UI, it's possible to "Share" a photo on my wall - that's almost what i need but i don't know the Graph API equivalent for that operation (if there's any)

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "me/links"

passing http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=**** as a link

Comment: Unfortunately this method no longer appears to work and results in the following error:

(#1500) The url you supplied is invalid

I haven't found a workaround for this.

Comment: I have the same question, do anybody know the correct answer?

Answer (score -1):

With the Graph API you can share the photo as a link.

this is the documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#links

You need send a POST request to me/feed/. And indeed send the link: http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[the id of the photo]

Make sure the publish_stream permission is allowed for the access_token.

with Jquery this is an example:

```
$.post( 
   'http://www.facebook.com/me/feed', 
   { 
     link: 'http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=[THE_PHOTO_ID], 
     access_token: [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
   }, 
   function(result) { console.log('shared'); },
   'text'
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as above, resulting in a 1500 error from Facebook.